# The user does not have permission to perform this action Entity Framwork after Update-database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, nuget

After copying and renaming my application, I made some changes on my model. but when I create a migration 'Add-Migration 201808190436285_ARPContext23 -Force' and try to apply the update 'update-database -verbose' I received the message 'The user does not have permission to perform this action.'

do you have an idea ??

Comment: You need to give the necessary privileges, for instance read, write and delete privileges to all tables to the user for which you are trying to connect to the underlying database with. How to do this depends on your DBMS

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER with windows authentication, and I have enabled db_datareader and db_datawriter for my user account in the securtity pane of the database in question.

but I still have the same message '' The user does not have permission to perform this action. ''

Answer (score 0):

> to apply the update 'update-database -verbose' I received the message
>   'The user does not have permission to perform this action.'
>
> . . .
>
> I have enabled db_datareader and db_datawriter for my user

To drop and create tables in SQL Server the user needs, at a minimum, the CREATE TABLE permission and the ALTER permission on the target schema.

More commonly, you would grant CONTROL on the database to your user, or the DB_OWNER fixed database role.